# Intercepting HTML5 video source request in Android WebView

Tags: android, video, webview, html5-video, android-webview

I have an app which shows a HTML5 page with a video element in a WebView. It took me a while to figure out how to get the video working, but finally I succeeded to play the video embedded in a WebView on an Samsung Galaxy Tab (Android 3.1). I used the following code for the video tag:

```
<video controls poster="img/poster.jpg" height="240" width="360">
        <source src="video/BigBuck.m4v">
        <source src="video/BigBuck.theora.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="video/BigBuck.webm" type="video/webm">
        HTML5 video not supported.
</video>
```

The video element has multiple sources and now I'm trying to capture the selected video source (and format) before the video starts to play. When I click the play button, I see a HTTP request for the video file arriving at the web server where the video files are stored, but I don't succeed in intercepting this request at the app-side.

I looked at several methods to see whether the request for the video file passes there, but I didn't saw it pass in any of them.

- In `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` in my `WebViewClient` only the initial HTML5 page request passes.
- In `shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url)` in my `WebViewClient` I see only passing the initial HTML5 page request and a request for the video poster image, but not for the video file.
- `onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback)` in my `WebChromeClient` is only called when I click the fullscreen control button on the HTML5 page when the video is already playing, but not when I click the play button. (What is actually the purpose of this method?)

Does anyone have a suggestion for another method where I can capture the request for the video file or can anyone explain me what actually happens when I click the play button on the video element?

Comment: Can you post the code you use for the video tag. I have very recently dealt with that and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` worked for me (in Gingerbread though).

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem using a javascript approach. When the HTML page is loaded, a `loadedmetadata` event is fired when the video metadata has been loaded. From that moment on you can get the selected video source from the `currentSrc` attribute of the video element and pass it via a `JavascriptInterface` to the Android native code.

Below is the code of the HTML5 video element. "Android" is the name by which the `JavascriptInterface`  can be accessed in javascript.

```
<video poster="image/poster.jpg" height="240" width="360" onloadedmetadata="Android.interceptPlay(this.currentSrc);">
    <source src="video/BigBuck.m4v">
    <source src="video/BigBuck.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video/BigBuck.theora.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    HTML5 video not supported.
</video>
```

The code of the JavascriptInterface

```
private class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /* Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void interceptPlay(String source) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And finally add the JavascriptInterface to the WebView at Activity creation time

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

It’s important to catch the `loadedmetadata` event by adding the `onloadedmetadata` attribute to the HTML5 video element and not by registering an event listener at page load via `addEventListener("loadedmetadata",...)` because on a fast network the `loadedmetadata` event may be fired before the listener is registered (see http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/consistent-event-firing-with-html5-video)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Erika; this looks like just what I need also.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I need to intercept the Play button the first time it's pressed (I'm downloading the video one time). Do you see an easy way to do that?

Comment: Did you ever find a "*real*" solution for this? I really need to intercept the url because in my case the event will never be triggered.