# Why isn't the video `src' being passed to `shouldInterceptRequest()'

Tags: android, video, webview

I have a `WebView` in an app that has a single purpose, load some HTML and render it. The content, is in a zip file and I have succeeded in passing an `InputStream` object for every request directly from the zip file without extracting it.

It all works very well and I can use the `WebView` with the content from the zip archive and it renders everything correctly, except that I have failed to make it play a video.

The video, is subject to the same constraint as all other resources. I would expect `shouldInterceptRequest()` to be called when the `WebView` needs to fetch the video resource, but it simply doesn't.

I am sure that the problem is when loading the file, the `WebView` apparently tries a local file and when it fails it tries to fetch it from a server.

My Application, has no internet permission and it's intended for offline use. Also, I have a custom URI scheme defined and it's working quite well.

Just with

```
webView.loadUrl("myscheme://myresource/index.html")
```

and then in the `shouldInterceptRequest()` I do intercept and resolve the file name, find it in the zip archive, get an `InputStream` and the rest is very simple. Except because it's not working for video `src`.

I would accept any solution that works because at this point, I just want it to work. But I prefer

1. Of course, make it work just like it does with every other resource.
2. Make a custom URI resolver or the equivalent with the appropriate terminology, in principle this would just respond to anything that is requested through my custom scheme. This should work just the way `WebView` internally passes something to the `setDataSource()` method of the `MediaPlayer` object used to display the video.

Comment: Since you own the local HTML file,  have you tried with any javascript solution? There is one relevant thread here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999712/intercepting-html5-video-source-request-in-android-webview

Comment: I don't want a javascript solution, it's not a solution it's a workaround. I did not say taht I "*own*" the HTML file, I can't in principle control it's contents. In this case I do, but it's not a rule. Also, of course I have read that post.